# Buffer Reader reading String with comma, Then inserting 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, split, 2d, bufferedreader

My proccesos.txt has this

`1,500,600
2,300,800
3,800,1000
4,200,5000`

What im trying to do here is insert the procesos.txt in a 2d array that will be displaying as follow 4 rows with 3 columns but without the comamas

This is currently my code on the buttom

`

```
 try {

       String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Ifrahim\\Desktop\\Procesos.txt"));
        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Ifrahim\\Desktop\\Procesos.txt"));

        int lines = (int) br2.lines().count();
         myArr = new int[lines][3];

         String[] lineArray = null ;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {


            lineArray=sCurrentLine.split(",");

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineArray));     
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: I want to insert it in myArr[][]

Answer (score 0):

```
int line = 0;
while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
     String[] tmp = sCurrentLine.split(",");//split the line up into its separate values

     for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
          myArr[line][i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[i]);
          //convert the values into integers and insert them at the matching position
          //in the array


     line++;
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could include some explanation of your answer, for the benefit of people who might not fully understand your implementation.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException i get a this error on myArr[line][i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[i]);

Comment: could you comment the complete first line of the stacktrace pls?

Comment: i've tested the code. works fine for me. maybe some variable you haven't initialized?